# Dotnet core Web Api 3.1 deploy to docker failing

Tags: docker, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I tried to containerize an existing Dotnetcore Web API but i see the following error after running the container.
[image]

My project structure

`Marketplace
|
|__ Dockerfile
|
|__ Marketplace.Backend|
                       |__Marketplace.API___ Marketplace.API.csproj
                       |
                       |__Markplace.Common__ Marketplace.Common.csproj`

This is my dockerfile

```js
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY Marketplace.BackEnd/ ./src
WORKDIR /app/src
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/src/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app/marketplace.api.dll"]
```

I can verify that the generated image contains marketplace.api.dll inside app folder
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your working dir is /app, and then you try to run

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app/marketplace.api.dll"]
```

I think you wanted

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "marketplace.api.dll"]
```

Also, be aware that file systems in Docker are case sensitive, so you might actually have wanted

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Marketplace.Api.dll"]
```

Comment: Didn't know that file systems in Docker are case sensitive, the error that SDK was missing made me think in a different direction. Thanks!

Comment: Windows containers aren't case-sensitive, but linux ones are.

Comment: Got no experience with Windows containers, but that one sure looks like a Linux container!